# I want to be more present (for/with) my children

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, difference

I want to be more present for/with my children.

What's the difference (if any) between using 'for' and 'with' here?

Comment: The problem is that "more present" isn't right. You are either present or you are not. It would be more colloquial to say, "I want to spend more time with my children" or I want to be with my children more often."

Comment: **For** = for the benefit of the children. **With** = in their company. (Agreed that 'more present' is incorrect.)